# Read from analog then cast not showing the correct value

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to read the analog value of the light sensor and print its percentage but for unknown reasons I'm getting negative values when I'm printing the value.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  // Let's say 1002 is the analogValue
  int analogValue = (int) analogRead(0);

  // get the percentage
  int value = 100 * analogValue / 1023;

  Serial.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
  Serial.println(analogValue); // print the analog value 0...1023
  Serial.println(100 * analogValue); // just for test
  Serial.println(value); // The percentage
  Serial.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

  delay(500);
}
```

I don't know what's going in background, but I'm getting negative values when I try to print the percentage:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1002
-30772
-30
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2):

Max value for `int` is 32,767. But 100 * 1002 = 100,200. You are overflowing the `int`. Use `unsigned long`. Or `float` and cast to `int` when printing.

Comment: Simplest would be to replace `100` by `100L`.

Comment: Yes, but OP would have to be sure to do that on both lines - the original calculation as well as the `Serial.println` line (even though it's "just for test").  Either way works, though.